# What happens when you get backstabbed while being buffed by the Battalion's Backup?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-soldier

The backstab is a guaranteed critical hit from behind for 600% of your maximum health.

The Battalion's Backup, when activated, makes you immune to critical hits and minicrits (you receive regular damage instead) and, on top of that, it provides you with 35% damage resistance.

What happens when you combine the two things? Do you get 26 damage (65% of regular knife damage)? Do you still take damage for 600% health?

Comment: The difference between taking 600% and reduced damage (390%) is how it then interacts with things such as the dead ringer or the phlogistinator taunt.

Answer (score 8):

**Backstabs under the effect of [Batallion's Backup](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Battalion%27s_Backup) still deal a lethal amount of damage**, as this video sets out to show:

From http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Critical_hits:

> Critical hits deal 300% of the base damage of the weapon ...
>
> The Spy's melee weapons always and only crit on backstabs, **boosting the damage of a backstab *from 2x* the victim's current health to 6x**.

From: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Backstab

> Backstabs deal damage equal to 600% of the target's current health and always deal critical hits, **unless otherwise prevented by a Battalion's Backup**. However, a Battalion's Backup **will not cause a damage reduction**.

(Backstabs deal a base damage of 200% of the target's current health, and triple that [600%] on a crit. If the crit is removed, it will go back down to 200% of the current health; still lethal.)

Battalion's Backup **does** prevent backstabs from landing a critical hit (600% current health), however it **does not** reduce the non-crit damage of the backstab which is still lethal (200% current health).

While under the effect of Batallion's Backup, this would simply reduce the damage from 600% to 200% of the player's **current health**. They could have 1,000,000 health and a non-critical backstab would still deal 2,000,000 damage; a lethal amount. (6,000,000 if it criticals; also lethal)

Whether you deal 2x a target's current  health, or 6x a target's current health, they are both lethal amounts. Anything equal to or greater than 1x a target's current health will be lethal.

---

**The [Phlogistinator](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Phlog)'s 75% reduced damage buff does *not* protect against backstabs.**

From: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Phlog

> Once filled, it can be activated with the secondary fire command or taunting (default key 'G'), which performs a taunt that will refill health completely and enable a short crit boost. **During this taunt, the wielder has 75% damage resistance (however, this does not protect against damage from Backstabs).**

---

**Backstabs deal 10% damage to spies using the Dead Ringer.** 6x current health will instead be 0.6x current health. 2x current health (a non crit backstab such as one being affected by the Battalion's Backup) will instead deal 0.2x current health.

From: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Dead_ringer

> The **Dead Ringer blocks 90% of the damage from the activating hit as well as during the first 6.5 seconds of the feign death Cloak**.  This allows the player to survive fully charged headshots by Snipers, **backstabs from enemy Spies**, and Taunt kills as long as the user has a sufficient amount of Health before the attack was made. **Since backstabs have a base damage of 6 times the victim's current health, and the initial hit that activates the Dead Ringer does 10% damage, backstabs will deal 6/10 of the Spy's current health.**

Comment: OKay, this is a partial answer. However - is it 600% damage or 390% damage you take? What about people activating the Phlog?

Comment: @badp Answer updated. Phlog does not protect against backstabs.

Comment: Uh, so what does "unless otherwise prevented by a Battalion's Backup" mean? It's kinda contradictory :) This is why I would've rather seen this done as science rather than grabbing wiki articles I've already read and seeing what they add up to. Also backstab damage being defined by your current health is wrong; it's based on your max health (and overheal is a thing.)

Comment: As the next quote shows, the backstab deals 6x current hp when it crits, 2x current hp when it doesn't crit. Battalion's Backup DOES remove the crit on a backstab, but the backstab will STILL deal lethal damage even without the crit (2x current hp is double the life you have; you always die from a backstab whether or not it crits).

Comment: The wiki is not gospel. The wiki stating that backstab damage is based on your _current_ health is simply _wrong._ Where does "2x" come from anyway?!

Comment: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/ is administered by Valve staff. The Backstab page (if you check the top right of it) is a Featured article. Featured articles must contain accurate information, approved by the administration (includes Valve staff). http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Help:Group_rights

The information is accurate.

2x = 200%; the base damage that a backstab does when it does NOT crit. (crit = 6x or 600% damage) (non-crit = 2x or 200% damage)

If this information is "simply wrong", please go ahead and cite your legitimate source(s).

Comment: @badp In all seriousness, if you can cite a valid source proving otherwise, or provide some tests of your own, I would be glad to redact my answer. I've read nothing to suggest max hp instead of current hp, but it could very well be the case. There is a chance that these wiki articles are incorrect, however (as my previous comment noted), these articles should be fairly well maintained and reliable. If you need to go as far as obtaining source code or observing detailed tests in order to feel confident in an answer, best of luck.

Comment: I've watched some youtube videos and the current health thing seems to be correct after all, which means I have some revising of recent posts to do. I'll be doing science tomorrow after my exam :)

Comment: For me, the "2x" comes from playtesting with the Dead Ringer on a no-crit server.

Comment: Changes to Phlog. Answer inaccurate. That video may be outdated, as well (though yes, the mechanic for generating rage doesn't affect the specific mechanics of popping the banner).

Answer (score 0):

The Battalion's Backup has two effects. It reduces damage taken by 35%, and turns critical hits into normal hits.

A backstab's base damage is 2x the victim's current HP, but is also usually a crit, so that normally raises the damage to 6x the victim's current HP.

Under the influence of the Backup's buff, a backstab deals (200% * (1.00 - .35)) = 130% of the victim's current HP.

This is, obviously, still enough damage to kill anyone.